# Docker tags are lost between steps in Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, gradle, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using [Bitbucket pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) to build Docker images with Gradle. Here is my build:

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-docker
        name: Build Docker images
        image:
          name: openjdk:8
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - ./gradlew dockerBuildImage
          - docker image ls
        caches:
          - gradle-wrapper
          - gradle
          - docker
    - step: &publish-docker
        name: Publish Docker images
        image:
          name: docker
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - docker image ls
        caches:
          - docker
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build-docker
    - step: *publish-docker
```

My `build.gradle.kts` is configured to tag the images with UTC timestamps:

```
configure<DockerExtension> {
    configure(this.getProperty("javaApplication"), closureOf<DockerJavaApplication> {
        baseImage = "openjdk:8-jre-alpine"
        tag = "${name}:${Instant.now().epochSecond}"
    })
}
```

When I run `dockerBuildImage` task locally, I can see my tagged images:

```
$docker image ls
REPOSITORY     TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
…
forklift-1     1540454741   93fd78260bd1   5 weeks ago   105MB
forklift-2     1540454741   3c8e4e191fd3   5 weeks ago   105MB
forklift-3     1540454741   1e80caffd59e   5 weeks ago   105MB
forklift-4     1540454741   0e3d9c513144   5 weeks ago   105MB
…
```

The output from the "build-docker" step is like:

```
REPOSITORY                  TAG            IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
forklift-1                  1543511971     13146b26fe19   1 second ago     105MB
forklift-2                  1543511971     7581987997aa   3 seconds ago    105MB
forklift-3                  1543511971     a6ef74a8530e   6 seconds ago    105MB
forklift-4                  1543511970     a7087154d731   10 seconds ago   105MB
<none>                      <none>         cfc622dd7b3c   3 hours ago      105MB
<none>                      <none>         f17e20778baf   3 hours ago      105MB
<none>                      <none>         75cc06f4b5ee   3 hours ago      105MB
<none>                      <none>         1762b4f89680   3 hours ago      105MB
openjdk                     8-jre-alpine   2e01f547f003   5 weeks ago      83MB
```

But the output of the second step does not have any tags, though the sizes of the images are roughly equivalent:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
<none>       <none>   cfc622dd7b3c   3 hours ago   105MB
<none>       <none>   f17e20778baf   3 hours ago   105MB
<none>       <none>   75cc06f4b5ee   3 hours ago   105MB
<none>       <none>   1762b4f89680   3 hours ago   105MB
```

**Where are the tags lost**?

Note that some of the image IDs from the second step (`docker image ls`) seems to be same to those printed in the first step.

P.S. I know that if I need the tags (e.g. to publish) I can just do both build and publish in a single step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was not able to track down the root cause, I made a simple workaround based on Docker's [`save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) and [`load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) commands and [Bitbucket Pipelines' artifacts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/using-artifacts-in-steps-935389074.html).

First, I've changed the tagging scheme a little bit:

```
configure<DockerExtension> {
    configure(this.getProperty("javaApplication"), closureOf<DockerJavaApplication> {
        baseImage = "openjdk:8-jre-alpine"
        tag = "${name}:${System.getenv("DOCKER_TAG")}"
    })
}
```

So instead of the UTC timestamp I rely on an environment variable `DOCKER_TAG` that I can set externally.

Then, define "build-docker" step as following:

```
- step: &build-docker
    name: Build Docker images
    image:
      name: openjdk:8
    services:
      - docker
    script:
      - export DOCKER_TAG=${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
      - ./gradlew dockerBuildImage
      - docker save
        --output images.tar
        forklift-1:${DOCKER_TAG}
        forklift-2:${DOCKER_TAG}
        forklift-3:${DOCKER_TAG}
        forklift-3:${DOCKER_TAG}
    artifacts:
      - images.tar
    caches:
      - gradle-wrapper
      - gradle
```

I'm ok with using build numbers as tags, but any value can be provided.

Finally, the step that pushes the images is:

```
- step: &publish-docker
    name: Publish Docker images
    image:
      name: docker
    services:
      - docker
    script:
      - docker load --input images.tar
      - docker image ls
      - docker push …
```

This works, because `docker save`

> Produces a tarred repository to the standard output stream. Contains all parent layers, **and all tags + versions**, or specified repo:tag, for each argument provided.